# DXA Model Service upgrade

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are using DXA 2.0 Java with DXA Model Service 2.0 including hotfix CD_10.1.0.8270. Recently SDL team has released SDL DXA Model Service 2.0.3(https://github.com/sdl/dxa-model-service/releases/tag/DXA_2.0.3_Hotfix)

can we apply this hotfix?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's good to apply and important to understand the new changes and fixes included in the hotfix.

@Rick Pannekoek did a great presentation about **"Beyond SDL Tridion Sites DXA 2.0"** and explained about this Hotfix releases of DXA 2.0 changes.

**DXA Model Service "in-process"**

- Much better performance using in-process CD APIs instead of CIL

  - No HTTP/OData (de-)serialization overhead
  - Much less ADF overhead
  - Leverages Tridion Object Cache (incl. cache invalidation)

[image]

**Note:**

- Tightly coupled DXA 2.0.X -> CD 8.5
- Dependency on non-public CD artifacts

[For DXA 2.0, how to install the DXA_2.0.X hotfix for the Model service?](https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/FAQ/000009348?articleName=000008118)

I hope it helps.